# css animation for any padding value

Tags: css, animation, padding

I have a series of div that can have their own padding values. Some of them have in addition the following "autoClose" class to make them totally disappear (not only hidden but shrinked to 0px)

```
.autoClose {
    animation: shrinkDiv 5s forwards;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}
@keyframes shrinkDiv {
   from  {opacity: 1; height: auto; padding: 20px 10px 20px 40px;}
   to    {opacity: 0; height: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}
}
```

Is it possible to have `20px 10px 20px 40px` padding value (as example in the 'from' line) depending on the actual padding value of the concerned div without using javascript ?

Comment: If the answer solved your problem please set it as the accepted answer, thanks

Comment: I didn't know the from was optionnal. Thank you for the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude the "from" attribute from your animation. It should take the padding of the div automatically. Code example;

```
.autoClose {
    animation: shrinkDiv 5s forwards;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}
@keyframes shrinkDiv {
   to    {opacity: 0; height: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dqup2bvL/7/